# PyAudio: how to capture internal audio (not from microphone)?

Tags: python, pyaudio

Tried like this:

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
            channels=CHANNELS,
            rate=RATE,
            output=True,
            frames_per_buffer=chunk)

all = []
for i in range(0, int(RATE / chunk * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(chunk)
```

but it throws **paCanNotReadFromAnOutputOnlyStream**

Using input=True it reads audio from mic, but that is not what I need.
Any help, please

Edit: I am using linux

I can also use other library, not only PyAudio. I just need to get this work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Record speakers output with PyAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573556/record-speakers-output-with-pyaudio)

Answer (score 2):

Try this: https://github.com/intxcc/pyaudio_portaudio

PyAudio isn't made to record outputs, only inputs.  This fork however introduces an api that gives you the ability to do so through loopback mode.  To use this, set the flag as AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_LOOPBACK.  Hopefully this works and good luck!

Comment: I am using linux

Comment: @ AshFTW What if you used a male to male 3.5mm jack? You could also get a 3.5mm splitter so one output can go to your headphones and one could go to the computer mic jack.

Comment: [paste] splint.png