# Default speaker output for all OSes

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pyaudio

I have been previously using pyaudio to get sound from the system (not mic) audio output, but had to specify the system output device ID manually. Is there a *default* **device name** that is used for inner system audio output for **all Operating Systems**?

For example, from  [Record speakers output with PyAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573556/record-speakers-output-with-pyaudio), I see that user macost has suggested to use: "Stereo Mix (Realtek(R) Audio)", but is that ID general to all OS?

```
for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
    dev = p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
    if (dev['name'] == 'Stereo Mix (Realtek(R) Audio)' and dev['hostApi'] == 0): # THIS LINE
        dev_index = dev['index'];
        print('dev_index', dev_index)
```

Found the code from [Record speakers output with PyAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573556/record-speakers-output-with-pyaudio),
but want to know, whether Realtek ID is common to everything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After gaining more experience, I understood that asking PC to select default speaker on any OS is too much.
Better approach would be to let your user choose Microphone and Speakers by providing a list of available devices and let them check if it's working as expected:

- first, let them check speakers by making a ping or any other sound from user selected *possible* speaker device
- for Mic, let them record themselves and hear the output, if it's correct one

It's pretty easy to do and demo of it can be seen in any common video call apps, such as Zoom.