# How to get desktop audio with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyaudio

I am trying to make a screen recorder with python. I have figured out how to record the screen with `cv2.VideoWriter` and `pyautogui.screenshot()`, what I can't figure out is how I can also record the desktop audio and merge it with the video that I am recording. I also need the screen capture and the audio capture to run simultaneously. They need to start and stop at command. I've looked into `pyaudio` but I can't understand it. Can anyone help me out?

**Update:**

I have figured out how to use pyaudio and when researching about it, I found out about portaudio from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37218364/13799055. With my newly acquired knowledge, I wrote this code.

```
import pyaudio
import wave

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
    print(i, p.get_device_info_by_index(i)["name"])

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 16000
CHUNK = 1 * RATE
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
PATH = "tmp.mp3"

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                input_device_index=0,
                as_loopback=True)

frames = []

for _ in range(int((RATE / CHUNK) * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

wf = wave.open(PATH, "wb")
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b"".join(frames))
wf.close()
```

For some reason, it is not working and is still taking input from my microphone. It is having no errors though. This is what the devices loop shows:

```
0 Microsoft Sound Mapper - Input
1 Microphone (High Definition Aud
2 CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual
3 Microphone (Voicemod Virtual Au
4 Microphone (SplitCam Audio Mixe
5 Microsoft Sound Mapper - Output
6 Speakers (High Definition Audio
7 CABLE Input (VB-Audio Virtual C
8 Line (Voicemod Virtual Audio De
9 CABLE Input (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)
10 Speakers (High Definition Audio Device)
11 Line (Voicemod Virtual Audio Device (WDM))
12 CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)
13 Microphone (Voicemod Virtual Audio Device (WDM))
14 Microphone (SplitCam Audio Mixer)
15 Microphone (High Definition Audio Device)
16 Output (@System32\drivers\bthhfenum.sys,#4;%1 Hands-Free HF Audio%0
;(Anonymous Streamer))
17 Input (@System32\drivers\bthhfenum.sys,#4;%1 Hands-Free HF Audio%0
;(Anonymous Streamer))
18 CABLE Output (VB-Audio Point)
19 Speakers (VB-Audio Point)
20 Microphone ()
21 Microphone (HD Audio Microphone 2)
22 Speakers (HD Audio Headphone/Speakers)
23 Headset (@System32\drivers\bthhfenum.sys,#2;%1 Hands-Free AG Audio%0
;(Synth))
24 Headset (@System32\drivers\bthhfenum.sys,#2;%1 Hands-Free AG Audio%0
;(Synth))
25 Headphones ()
26 Microphone (VAD Wave)
27 Line Out (VAD Wave)
28 Headset (@System32\drivers\bthhfenum.sys,#2;%1 Hands-Free AG Audio%0
;(Bluetooth music))
29 Headset (@System32\drivers\bthhfenum.sys,#2;%1 Hands-Free AG Audio%0
;(Bluetooth music))
30 Headphones ()
```

Can anyone help me fix up my code?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific need pyaudio is for sure a good way to go. This should get you started:

```
import pyaudio,

sr = 16000
chunk = 1 * sr
channel_nr = 1

audio_interface = pyaudio.PyAudio()
audio_stream = audio_interface.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                                    channels=channel_nr,
                                    rate=sr,
                                    input=True,
                                    frames_per_buffer=chunk)

audio_stream.start_stream()
```

Comment: Please see my edits, thanks to your help I've gotten pretty far

Comment: @Ultra looks like OP didnt accept your edit. Can you comment/answer?