# Python Sounddevice: How to record the system audio? In other words, record whatever is coming through the computer speakers

Tags: python, portaudio, python-sounddevice

I'm looking to use Python SoundDevice to record the system audio.  In other words, instead of using a microphone to detect sounds, I just want to pull into my sounddevice.InputStream() whatever would normally be coming out of the speakers of my computer.

I've found various techniques to doing this with PyAudio([Here, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892199/detect-record-audio-in-python/892293#892293)), but I **need to use SoundDevice for this.**  How can I access system audio?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Record speakers output with PyAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573556/record-speakers-output-with-pyaudio)

Comment: Russ J, unfortunately no.  I'm using SoundDevice, not PyAudio.  It isn't clear how I would adapt the code in that example for Sounddevice.