# Live stereo sound visualization

Tags: python, audio, visualization

I am creating a simple program that visualizes stereo sound. The program code below shows the visualization from mirophone (input) only. I want the visualization to work from the output (system sound).

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np

maxValue = 2**16
p=pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=44100, input=True, output=True, frames_per_buffer=1024, output_device_index=3)


while True:
    data = np.fromstring(stream.read(1024),dtype=np.int16)
    dataL = data[0::2]
    dataR = data[1::2]
    peakL = np.abs(np.max(dataL)-np.min(dataL))/maxValue
    peakR = np.abs(np.max(dataR)-np.min(dataR))/maxValue

    print("left", round(peakL, 2))
    print("right", round(peakR, 2))
```

Comment: Is your question "which device index is the system sound"?

Comment: Or is your question "which number of channels corresponds to stereo"?

Comment: my question is "which device index is the system sound"?

Comment: But none of these indexes act as outputs, only inputs

Comment: In the current version of this module, each device index acts as an input (microphone)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573556/record-speakers-output-with-pyaudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Linux:

1. Open PulseAudio Volume Control *
2. Go to the `Recording` tab
3. Start your script (or check it's already running).
4. Change the input of the new stream named `ALSA plug-in [python 3.8]` (or something very similar) to `Monitor of <your-audio-output-device>`

** On Debian-based systems you can install PulseAudio Volume Control using `sudo apt install pavucontrol`*

Also it may be worth checking out the `sounddevice` library, I switched over to it from `pyaudio` in my personal project a while ago and (personally) have found it's a little easier to work with. They are very, very similar in usage but `sounddevice` figures out a few things automatically that you need to figure out yourself with `pyaudio`.

I have a library that uses `sounddevice` that's part of a framework I'm developing that I think fulfills your needs (except it's non-blocking for real-time usage). Hopefully it's useful for reference: https://gitlab.com/volux/voluxaudio.

Let me know if you want clarification on anything, happy to help :)

Comment: Unfortunately I work on windows. But I solved this problem by using virtual cable.